# Declaring objects in the head of ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In the following code, I'm trying to declare an object of Player class in the header of ViewController.h and call its method in the ViewController.m. The problem is nothing happens and the methods are not being called. Can someone help me solving this issue

ViewController.h

```
#import "Player.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    __weak IBOutlet Player *player; 
}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)update
{
    if([player collision] == TRUE)
    {
        [player nextHead];
        [player drawTrail:@"green"];
    }

}
```

Comment: You have declared a pointer to an object?  Do you create the object somewhere and assign to the pointer?  (You call it `IBOutlet`.... Is it linked to an object from interface builder?)

Comment: Seems like your `player` is nil. Are you sure that your `player` object successfully instantiated in xib or in other code?

Comment: How can I create an object of a class in ViewController.h and invoke that object in the ViewController.m?

Comment: You don't create it in the @interface; you create it in some @implementation method.  Do you plan on using `Player` only within this one view controller?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes. only within the view controller

Comment: I sugges you look into properties for an extended answer to your problem: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Comment: In that case, the `init` method is the most probable place.  Something like: `player = [[Player alloc] init]` or whatever initialization method you define for `Player`.  (If you look up the docs for a class extension, you don't need to mention `player` in your .h file at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear of your setup, but to take a shot in the dark, are you trying to accomplish something like this:

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet Player *player;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *updateTimer;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     // fire time 10 times a second to call update
    _updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                            target:self 
                            selector:@selector(update) 
                            userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:YES];
}

-(void)update
{
    if([player collision] == TRUE)
    {
        [player nextHead];
        [player drawTrail:@"green"];
    }

}
```